# How to lock concurrent access to all struct fields internally?

Tags: go

How to lock concurrent access to all struct fields internally? Let's say I have a struct:

```
 type Data struct {
    ID string
    Size int
    //... and more fields
 }
```

That will be used in another struct:

```
type Project struct {
    mu sync.Mutex
    MetaData Data
    //... and more fields
}
```

How could I modify/get MetaData struct and use mutex for that while not exposing its mutex to the outer packages? I know I could use Get/Set methods, but what if I needed to modify one field of Data struct (it wouldn't be very good/clean if every field had a get/set method with the same shared mutex)? Could you recommend a way/pattern to have a struct-wise mutex that would be locked/unlocked internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
type Data struct {
    ID   string
    Size int
    //... and more fields
}

type Project struct {
    mu       sync.Mutex
    metaData Data
    //... and more fields
}

func (p *Project) AccessMetaData(f func(*Data)) {
    p.mu.Lock()
    defer p.mu.Unlock()
    f(&p.metaData)
}
```

Comment: Be careful, this does NOT Lock access! This establishes a lock for as long as it takes to get a pointer, then unlocks and returns the pointer, allowing the caller to make concurrent accesses, including writes, of the data, without any locking.

Comment: Yes, the function has to cooperate and only access the data while the function is executing and not save the pointer. But as long as the function you pass behaves correctly, it does what the OP was asking for.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it saves the pointer. It could call `AccessMetaData().Size` and the read of `Size` would execute outside the mutex lock in `AccessMetaData`.

Comment: `AccessMetaData` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this so I tested this, and if the parent struct is locked, the child struct is also locked. Try it locally as go playground seems to be deterministic.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type testGroup struct {
    sync.Mutex
    items map[string]*test
}

type test struct {
    x int
}

var str string = "test"

func increment(t *testGroup, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    t.Lock()
    t.items[str].x = t.items[str].x + 1
    t.Unlock()
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    var w sync.WaitGroup
    tg := testGroup{}
    tg.items = make(map[string]*test)
    tg.items[str] = &test{}
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        w.Add(1)
        go increment(&tg, &w)
    }
    w.Wait()
    fmt.Println("final value of x", tg.items[str].x)
}
```

Try commenting out `t.Lock()` and `t.Unlock()` in `increment()` function